# Are primitive variables garbage collected in C++

Tags: c++, function, garbage-collection

If there is a function like:

```
int func1() {
    int status = func2();

    // Do something with status.

    return status;
}
```

In the course of this function a variable status of type int is allocated memory and during the course of the function the variable is used and then returned from func1.

My question is, when is the memory garbage collected for this primitive, or does it remains in memory for ever?

Comment: C++ doesn't have a garbage collector.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Basic_architecture_of_a_stack

Comment: That being said, it's likely that most C++ compilers generate code that puts `status` on the stack (see answers below), but I dare say that is implementation-specific. One would probably have to check with the C++ language specification to give a conceptually correct, implementation-independent answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, *status* variable is allocated in the stack and will be freed immediately after *func1* returns.

Answer (score 2):

The memory is allocated from the stack.  When the function is called the stack pointer will be incremented enough to hold the function parameters, locals, return value (possibly), and return address.  When the function returns, the stack pointer is decremented by exactly the same amount and control resumes at the return address.

In other words, the `status` declaration would cause the stack pointer to be incremented an extra `sizeof(int)` bytes (possibly more if the compiler decides to for the sake of alignment).

Comment: What if the stack size is exhausted, does it throws stack overflow error.

Comment: @AnkitZalani This depends on the environment, but usually you would receive at least some kind of error (such as SIGSEGV on Linux).